# Proper way to call web service using rest in android?

Tags: android

Please suggest any solution?
I'm new to android.I'm getting error while invoking web service

```
W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Method Not Allowed
```

Here is my activity which calls a web service(method) which takes one string parameter and gives output. I'd be glad if anybody posts code snippet using asynctask becos it is most preferred way to call service in android....

```
public class closingBalance extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected final String NAMESPACE = "http://xxxxx/";

    protected final String METHOD_NAME = "getReportDetails";
    protected final String URL = "http://xxxxx?wsdl?shop_num=12345";

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpResponse res = client.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
        StatusLine line  = res.getStatusLine();
        if(line.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            res.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            String response = out.toString();
            System.out.println(response);
            out.close();

        }else{
            res.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw  new IOException(line.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this web service has wsdl file and how can i consume it using rest,volley or retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to research the Volley tool can be very useful to you.

Transmitting Network Data Using Volley is very simple

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: But this web service has wsdl file and how can i consume it using rest?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [**Retrofit**](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library.

[**Here**](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/) is a comparison between AsyncTask, Volley and Retrofit